# Combine duplicate rows to output a single row

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates

I have a table for a ticket system that has the following cols;

```
order<string> startDate<datetime> endDate<datetime>
```

The majority of rows are not duplicated based on a column 'order' however in the scenario where an 'order' crosses from one day to the next it is split into 2 orders, the 1st has an endDate of 5pm (end of day) and the 2nd has a startDate of 8am (start of day). Their corresponding start and end dates are as needed.
Some orders can be >2 days long and so will be split into >2 rows.

example

```
order startDate endDate
1 2016-03-29 11:00:53.000 2016-03-29 17:00:53.000
1 2016-03-30 08:00:53.000 2016-03-30 12:48:53.000
2 2016-03-30 10:17:53.000 2016-03-30 13:08:53.000

would transform to 
1 2016-03-29 11:00:53.000 2016-03-30 12:48:53.000
2 2016-03-30 10:17:53.000 2016-03-30 13:08:53.000
```

I need to combine all rows to give me a table of unique 'order' ids with start and ends. i.e. a row with the lowest start date of its duplicates and highest enddate of its duplicates.

I plan to do this by creating a new table and populating it and can choose 1 of duplicate rows based on a certain value but in not sure how to create a new row based on values from multiple rows.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT order, MIN(startDate), MAX(endDate)
FROM your_table_name
GROUP BY order
```

There may be no need to create a new table for this — `GROUP BY` queries are ***extremely*** common in production usage, and there's no inherent harm in simply running that query to get the results you need when you need them.

Comment: Thx VoteyDisiple. I am moving them to another table for an unrelated reason - i dont own the transfer script other than to direct the consumer to the right table. I know I know but that fights for later ;)